# How to limit the amount of pages in my Carousel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can I configure my number of pages per carousel to have a limit of `noOfPages`? I'm not sure how to implement this in my functions below.

```
  const itemsPerPage = 6;
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);
  const [noOfPages] = React.useState(
    Math.ceil(data[0]?.length / itemsPerPage)
  );

  const handleChangePage = (event, value) => {
    setPage(value);
  };

  const next = (event, value) => {
    setPage(page + 1);
  };

  const prev = (event, value) => {
    setPage(page - 1);
  };

return(
          <Carousel
            onClick={handleChangePage}
            next={next}
            prev={prev}
            indicators
            cycleNavigation
            swipe
            animation="slide"
          >
)
```

The idea is that `data` is dynamic, so the value of `noOfPages` is not static and will vary often. How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: My Carousel component comes from https://github.com/Learus/react-material-ui-carousel, It is a 3rd party library not developed by Material-UI. Material-UI does not have any carousel component available at this time.

Added some more code for a better understanding how my Carousel works.

```
          <Carousel
            onClick={handleChangePage}
            next={next}
            prev={prev}
            indicators
            cycleNavigation
            swipe
            animation="slide"
          >
            <Grid container spacing={5} alignItems="flex-end">
              {data[0]?.slice((page - 1) * itemsPerPage, page * itemsPerPage)
                .map((data, index) =>
                {
                      return (
                      
                        <Grid item key={index} xs={4} md={4}>
                            <Card>
                            <CardHeader
                            title={<Chip label={data.symbol} />} 
                            subheader={data.adj_close}        
                            />      
                            <CardContent >
                                <div>
                              <MiniGraphs
                                historicalPrice={historicalPrice.filter(i => i.symbol === data.symbol)}
                                dateRange={date}
                              />
                                </div>              
                            </CardContent>
                            </Card>
                        </Grid>
                    );
                })}
        </Grid>
        </Carousel>
```

Also added a sandbox to represent the current state of the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-curie-5qck3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You don't need to create a state for it, if `Carousel` accepts a limit, then just pass `Math.ceil(data[0]?.length / itemsPerPage)` directly as a prop to it.

Comment: Carousel does not accept a limit: https://github.com/Learus/react-material-ui-carousel

Comment: You might want to include that `Carousel` is from material UI in your post. In this case, you could divide your data array into chunks of length defined by `itemsPerPage`, see: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-divide-array-js/

Comment: I updated my post about where this library comes from. Just to be clear, Material-UI does not develop this library. It is a 3rd party library created by an independent developer.

Comment: @gptt916, that is actually what I do, the problem with my current set-up above, is that the state confuses the carousel to continuously keep incrementing(changing slides/pages) even if it runs out of content to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a max in your `next` and `prev` methods, you cannot indefinitely increment the pages. do something like

```js
  // if you dont want the carousel to loop when reaching first/last page
  const noLoopNext = (event, value) => {
    setPage((currPage) => {
      if (currPage + 1 > Math.ceil(SymbolData.length / itemsPerPage)) {
        return currPage;
      } else {
        return currPage + 1;
      }
    });
  };

  const noLoopPrev = (event, value) => {
    setPage((currPage) => {
      if (currPage === 1) {
        return currPage;
      } else {
        return currPage - 1;
      }
    });
  };

  // if you want it to loop around
  const loopNext = (event, value) => {
    setPage((currPage) => {
      if (currPage + 1 > Math.ceil(SymbolData.length / itemsPerPage)) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return currPage + 1;
      }
    });
  };

  const loopPrev = (event, value) => {
    setPage((currPage) => {
      if (currPage === 1) {
        return Math.ceil(SymbolData.length / itemsPerPage);
      } else {
        return currPage - 1;
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: When I add your code I'm getting a ` Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression`

Comment: Sorry, I edited the code to make it a bit cleaner but forgot a `return` keyword at the front, edited.

Comment: Not sure I understand your code, where is `currPage` meant to be coming from? The Carousel doesn't seem to move when I implement this snippet.

Comment: the `currPage` is a part of using functional update for react state hooks, see: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates. Could you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I'm would need to see some more code to help further.

Comment: Hey Nick, thank you for helping me out. Please checkout this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-curie-5qck3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Check out https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-frog-vttdo?file=/src/App.js, depending on what behaviour you want, i.e. loop around or stop at first and last, you can pick which functions you want to use

Comment: Thank you very much for the help